# Status bar color not changing with navigationBar when implemented in tabbedView

Tags: ios, statusbar, navigationbar, swiftui, tabbed-view

I was trying to use navigationView in tabbedView with SwiftUI but when I embedded navigationView in tabbedView, status bar color stopped changing. If we try to use just navigationView without tabbedView, status bar color changed. Please have a look at the picture below, this is what I am getting. Let me know if there is any workaround for this. 
Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: TabView (tabbedView is deprecated)

Comment: Yes I am using beta 4. Lots of forEach issues in beta 5

Comment: Please provide your code so that we can try to figure it out your actual issue